# Sum up all keypress inside an Iframe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, iframe

I've created a simple website using AppScript. In my page I have a disabled box and 3 columns of iframe embedded with my work tools. (I've change the URL for privacy purposes)

Here's my website: 
[image: Workspace]

What I need is, once I click on any iframe and open my working tool and pressed one of these letters (A,S,D, 'Shift+Enter',U,Y,T & N) it will count how many times did I pressed that letters inside the iframe and display the value in the disabled box above my website. I have 3 iframe and whenever I choose will have the same outcome.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<style>
body {
 margin: 0;
}

.row {
 display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.embed-responsive {
 position: relative;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.embed-responsive::before {
 display: block;
 content: "";
}

.embed-responsive .embed-responsive-item {
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
}

.col-md-4 {
 width: 100%;
 padding: 15px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
 .col-md-4 {
  max-width: 33.33333%;
  flex: 0 0 33.33333%;
 }
}
</style>

</head>
    <body onload="window.resizeTo(600,800)">
    <input type="text" placeholder="total ticket" style="margin-left:19px;" disabled >
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="URL HERE" width="98%" height="1000px" ></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="URL HERE" width="98%" height="1000px"></iframe>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
              <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="URL HERE" width="98%" height="1000px"></iframe>
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
function isCharacterKeyPress(evt) {
    if (typeof evt.which == "undefined") {
        // This is IE, which only fires keypress events for printable keys
        return true;
    } else if (typeof evt.which == "number" && evt.which > 0) {
        // In other browsers except old versions of WebKit, evt.which is
        // only greater than zero if the keypress is a printable key.
        // We need to filter out backspace and ctrl/alt/meta key combinations
        return !evt.ctrlKey && !evt.metaKey && !evt.altKey && evt.which != 8;
    }
    return false;
}

<input type="text" onkeypress="alert(isCharacterKeyPress(event))">
</script>
```

My JavaScript doesn't work. Is there someone who can help me?

Please help me, I've been struggling in this for a week now.

Comment: "Is there an alternative way to do it?" - does your way work? If not, then the alternative is a way that works. If it does work, then, what's the problem?

Comment: so ... are "URL HERE" same domain or cross (other) domain ... if cross domain, then just give up unless you also control the code at "URL HERE"

Comment: It's an other domain. Working tools from our clients. I've tried embedding it in my html and hoping that I can monitor all the tickets I'm working on. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: javascript can not access much in an iframe that is not the same domain ... there are ways .. but the code in the iframe has to cooperate ... `window.postMessage` is what you'll need

Comment: What does window.postMessage do? I'm sorry for asking too much.

Comment: The picture is showing three empty iframes. Is that correct?

Comment: About postMessage: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage (it is also new for me)

Comment: Yes it's showing an empty iframes. I remove the original URL due to our company's privacy.

Comment: I'll be reading that article regarding postMessage. Maybe it might help me solve the problem. But I'm not quite sure how will I do the coding cause I'm a beginner when it comes on coding.

Comment: Can someone help? Or even tell me if it's possible?